# Webclient change encoding mode conditionally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, encoding, spring-webclient

I have created WebClient bean as follow

```
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(final HttpClient httpClient) {
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(codecInmemoryMaxSize))
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
```

I am reusing the same bean to make HTTP calls like

```
public Mono<ResponseModel> get(final String url) {
        return webClient.get().uri(url)
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> clientResponse.toEntity(String.class)
                        .map(responseEntity -> new ResponseModel(responseEntity.getBody(), responseEntity.getStatusCode().value(),
                                CollectionUtils.toMultiValueMap(responseEntity.getHeaders().entrySet().stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))))));

    }
```

I want to set encoding mode conditionally while calling API. is there any way to do that?
I know there as way like to set factory like

```
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
        factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(codecInmemoryMaxSize))
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .uriBuilderFactory(factory)
                .build();
```

but these will apply as bean level so API follows the same encoding mode. I want to make it conditional while calling API.